# MySQL query to find employees salary greater than any manager

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So, I have this schema:

```
Emp(eid: integer,ename: string,age: integer,salary: real)
Works(eid:integer,did: integer,pct_time: integer)
Dept(did:integer,budget: real,managerid:integer)
```

I want to return the employees whose salary is greater that any manager (regardless of their department).

```
select E.ename, D.did, E.eid
from Emp E
join Works W ON E.eid = W.eid
join Dept D ON D.did = W.did
where E.salary > (select E2.salary from Emp E2, Dept D2 
                where E2.eid = D2.managerid)
```

But the sub query statement is returning more than one row. How can I compare multiple rows from 2 tables to get the correct result? Grouping should work, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement could be translated to finding out an employee who exist a manager that have salary lower than his salary.
You could try this.

```
 SELECT e.*
 FROM emp e
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM emp e2 INNER JOIN 
                               dept d2
                           ON e2.eid = d2.managerid 
                          WHERE  e2.salary < e.salary);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the employees whose salary is greater that any manager, then why dont you just find out all the employees who have a salary greater than the minimun salary of all managers?

```
select E.ename, D.did, E.eid
from Emp E
join Works W ON E.eid = W.eid
join Dept D ON D.did = W.did
where E.salary > (select min(E2.salary) 
                  from Emp E2, Dept D2 
                  where E2.eid = D2.managerid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need the `works` table.  The question is about *any* manager.  One way that you can write this is using `> all`:

```
select e.*
from emp e
where e.salary > all (select e2.salary
                      from emp e2 join
                           dept d2
                           on e2.eid = d2.managerid
                      );
```

You can run the subquery and see that it returns the salaries of all managers.  You want employees whose salary is greater than those.

EDIT:

Does this version work?

```
select e.*
from emp e
where e.salary > (select MAX(e2.salary)
                  from emp e2 join
                       dept d2
                       on e2.eid = d2.managerid
                 );
```

The `> all` may not work as expected if any salaries are `NULL`.

Comment: It's returning an empty table.